How can we test for Turing Completeness given any formal semantic specification?
I have seen the question asked many times always with the same answer: emulate a Turing machine on top of it. This seems like an ad hoc method so is there a more formal and general method to prove Turing completeness. I have also seen some say there are other ways of doing it within some formalism. So given an operation, denotational or axiomatic semantic specification how can we test if it is Turing complete based only upon the given rules. If this isn't possible why not is there a proof.
Assuming there is a general test could automate such a proof to create a general test given any formal semantic specification?
Furthermore is it possible to classify the capabilities of a formal semantic given only its definition on the Chomsky hierarchy or say what computational capabilities it has?
Any sources or further information would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

The concept of "formal semantic specification" itself is not formally defined, and even if it were, there would be no test for Turing-completeness.
Here is a family of models of computation C(M) parameterized by Turing machines such that C(M) is Turing-complete if and only if M doesn't halt. The model C(M) of "Turing machines under M" consists of Turing machines. A Turing machine N is run on an input tape at the same time as running M on the zero tape, and the execution halts whenever M or N halts first.

The idea of formalizing the concept of "formal semantic specification" (hereafter shortened to "formal system") is problematic in the first place. One attempt may look like this:
A formal system is a pair $(P,d)$ of a set of programs $P$ and a denotation function $d : P \to \mathbb{N} \rightharpoonup \mathbb{N}$ (note that the codomain consists of partial functions). A formal semantics is Turing-complete if the image of $d$ is the set of general recursive functions.
The issue is that most formal systems in the natural sense of the term are not intended to compute partial functions on natural numbers. The question "Is formal system X Turing-complete?" is dishonest because it relies on encoding X to fit the definition above and then implicitly assuming that it is the only way to use X to compute partial functions.
For example, it is well-known that primitive recursive functions are not Turing-complete. (You can replace "primitive recursive functions" with "simply-typed lambda calculus" in everything I'm saying here if you're more familiar with that.)
That corresponds to this formal semantics: $P$ is the set of primitive recursive definitions of type $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, and $d$ interprets them in the standard way. Obviously $(P,d)$ is not Turing-complete because it only computes total functions, whereas some general recursive functions are partial.
Here's another formal semantics that repurposes all of the same rules of how to interpret primitive recursive functions. Intuitively, we add a fuel parameter so we can simulate general recursion until we find the result or we run out of fuel. $P$ is the set of primitive recursive definitions of type $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, and for any $p \in P$, $d(p)(n) = m$ if and only if there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p$ (as a function $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$) maps $(n,k)$ to $m+1$ and for all $j < k$, $p$ maps $(n,j)$ to $0$ (this latter condition ensures the uniqueness of $m$). This formal system $(P,d)$ is Turing-complete. (See also Kleene's normal form theorem.)
Some people might object that this $(P,d)$ is not a faithful formalization of "primitive recursive functions". But the point is that there is no formal criterion of what is and is not a faithful formalization of an idea as a formal system. You could implement primitive recursive functions on a computer to use it as a programming language, and it would be perfectly legitimate to write a function that takes two natural numbers as parameters and set one of those to $2^{64}$ so you will never run out of fuel in practice. This is a way to implement general recursive function that is just as effective as implementing them in a "proper" Turing-complete language.
When we say that primitive recursive functions are not Turing-complete, this refers to a very specific formal claim, and the fallacy is to extrapolate it into a claim about "expressiveness", "what we can do with this system", which is not a formal notion. More generally, whether an arbitrary system is Turing-complete is an ill-posed question. If one did mean it as a formal question, they must have a particular encoding in mind as a pair $(P,d)$ or some other definition of "formal system"; confusion then arises because different people will come up with different formalizations to support their biases.
Turing-completeness is like hammers. We can all agree that most things, in their normal usage, are not hammers. But it is also true that everything can be a hammer if you find a way to hit with it hard enough. So it wouldn't be productive to formalize what it means to be a hammer: it either just confirms our biases about what is or is not a hammer, or everything is technically a hammer.
